# Unable to cast object (DataRowView to DataGridRow)

Tags: c#

Can someone explain this more detailed and maybe how can I fix this?

"unable to cast object of type system.data.DataRowView to type system.windows.controls.DataGridRow"

I had this error while trying to access the data inside a DataGrid while using a foreach loop.

```
private void GetSelectedRowCellValue()
        {
            foreach(DataGridRow row in tblPo.SelectedItems)
            {
                System.Data.DataRow Row = (System.Data.DataRow)row.Item;
                string value = Row["part_id"].ToString();

                prev.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what type is `tblPo.SelectedItems`? Which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: tblPo is the name of my datagrid. the exception is thrown during a "selectionchanged" event on the datagrid.

Comment: i need the data on tblPo data grid in order to output something on another data grid. is there another possible way on how to get a data inside a datagrid? thank u

Comment: And what code do you have for that `SelectionChanged` event? Can you post the *exact line* where the exception occurs? BTW, I asked for the type of `SelectedItems`. Can any item of that list be cast to `DataGridRow`, like you are trying to do?

Comment: The content of SelectionChanged event is just a function call for 'GetSelectedRowCellValue()' . The exception happens at 'foreach (DataGridRow row in tblPo.SelectedItems)' . What do u mean by type of SelectedItems? Does that refer to the type of data inside the datacells? Im sorry, im very new at c#

Comment: `DataGridRow row in tblPo.SelectedItems` is trying to assign each item of `SelectedItems` to a `DataGridRow`. Based on what you mention, it seems they cannot be cast. So, what type is `tblPo.SelectedItems[0]`, for example?

Comment: Any news, Kayl?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't solve the problem. The team changed the approach to the project. But sooner will still solve and study the problem stated above. Thank you!